# firebase realtime DB getting key of matched object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

My firebase realtime DB is structured like:

```
{
 "users" : {
    "P55dsK5xQaM3FhnsCcI5Oxnyi7v1" : {
      "email" : "myemail@gmail.com",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "name" : "Vik Kumar"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using angularfire2 to query data like below

```
getUserByEmail(email:string){
    console.log("start of getUserByEmail with email:" + email)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      {

        this.db.list("/users", 
          ref => ref.orderByChild('email').startAt(email)
        ).valueChanges().subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log('response:' + JSON.stringify(res))
            resolve(res)
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          }
        )
      })
  }
```

This works as expected. However, i need the id of this node "P55dsK5xQaM3FhnsCcI5Oxnyi7v1" as well to do some operations. How do i get that?

**My Business Use Case**
The users get added to note users node as they sign up. The above requirement came where an admin user want to update user data. So, he searches the user via his email and then update it.

So the above code is used to search users by email. Now, to be able to update i need to get the node id.

Comment: do you use firebase auth?

Comment: yes but that wont help.. as the user queried is not the one who is logged in

Comment: if you can elaborate your app workflow, it would definitely help, like how do you assign

Comment: added a bit of use case as well

Comment: "P55dsK5xQaM3FhnsCcI5Oxnyi7v1" is that your document name?

Comment: this is the auth id  of the user who signed up using fb.

Comment: Yes, I know, but do you store them in the database? Is it possible to screenshot your realtime database structure from firebase console?

Comment: well that is the real data. and yes i am storing it in db. each user node is by the document id which comes as auth id from fb.

Comment: Thats clear now, document id = user auth id right

Comment: yep you are right

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using AngularFire here. With the regular Firebase SDK for JavaScript, you can do this with:

```
getUserByEmail(email:string){
  console.log("start of getUserByEmail with email:" + email)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    firebase.database()
      .ref("/users")
      .orderByChild('email')
      .startAt(email)
      .once('child_added')
      .then(snapshot => {
        resolve(snapshot.key);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        reject(err)
      })
  });
}
```

By listening for `once('child_added'` we're getting a `snapshot` that only contains the first child node matching the query.

---

Note that the search now will match any user *after* the `email`, while I have a feeling you want to only find users starting **with** the value of `email`. In that case you'll want to add an `endAt()` clause too:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref("/users")
  .orderByChild('email')
  .startAt(email)
  .endAt(email+'\uF7FF')
  .once('child_added')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that

```
this.itemsRef = db.list('users');
this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
  .subscribe(actions => {
    actions.forEach(action => {
      console.log(action.type);
      console.log(action.key);
      console.log(action.payload.val());
    });
  });
```

Comment: this is not filtering the data using the email so how is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

So, actually i could do it using angularfire2 by replacing valueChanges to snapshotchanges as below

```
 getUserByEmail(email:string){
    console.log("start of getUserByEmail with email:" + email)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      { 
        this.db.list("/users", 
          ref => ref.orderByChild('email').startAt(email)
        ).snapshotChanges().subscribe(
          (res:any) => {
            console.log("resp length:" + res.length)
            //console.log('response:' + JSON.stringify(res))
            //console.log('key is::' + res.key())
            resolve(res)
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          }
        )
      })
  }
```

now res.key gives me key and res.payload.val() the data object.